# Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for MyOpportunitiesFilterPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: javascript, java, angular, ionic-framework

i want to show filter modal when i klik button, the modal is in My-Opportunities-Filter
but there is error "Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for MyOpportunitiesFilterPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?"

this is my-opportunities.module.ts

```
 @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        MyOpportunitiesPage,
        MyOpportunitiesFilterPage
      ],
      imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(MyOpportunitiesPage),
        SuperTabsModule
      ],
      exports:[
        MyOpportunitiesPage
      ],
      entryComponents: [
        MyOpportunitiesFilterPage
      ],
    })
    export class MyOpportunitiesPageModule {}
```

this is my-opportunities.ts

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-my-opportunities',
  templateUrl: 'my-opportunities.html',
})
export class MyOpportunitiesPage {
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
  private filterPage: Modal;
  
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public dataSerrvice : DataServiceProvider,
    private modalCtrl: ModalController
    ) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad MyOpportunitiesPage');
  }

  openTransaction() {
    this.navCtrl.push('MyOpportunitiesFilterPage');
  }

  private filter() {
    let filterPage: Modal = this.modalCtrl.create(MyOpportunitiesFilterPage, {
    });
    filterPage.present();
  }
```

this is my-opportunities-filter.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyOpportunitiesFilterPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(MyOpportunitiesFilterPage),
  ],
})
export class MyOpportunitiesFilterPageModule {}
```

i already add myOpportunitiesFilterPage in declaration, entrycomponets, but it still not works, can u guys help me

Comment: Why do you have a `MyOpportunitiesFilterPageModule` which declares `MyOpportunitiesFilterPage`, but also the `MyOpportunitiesPageModule` declares this component, and adds it to the entryComponents..

Comment: i adds MyOpportunitiesPageModule in entryComponents because i saw some links that use that to make it works, but i still confused honsetly

Answer (score 1):

i change my-opportunities.module like this, and its works

```
@NgModule({


 declarations: [
    MyOpportunitiesPage
    //MyOpportunitiesFilterPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(MyOpportunitiesPage),
    SuperTabsModule
  ],
  exports:[
    MyOpportunitiesPage
    //MyOpportunitiesFilterPage
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    MyOpportunitiesPage
    //MyOpportunitiesFilterPage
  ],
  providers: [
    MyOpportunitiesFilterPage
  ]
})
export class MyOpportunitiesPageModule {}
```